# Page redirects to site_url() in codeigniter. I have set paths in routes.php, it should go to page not found ?

Tags: codeigniter, routes

Page redirects to site_url() in codeigniter. I have set paths in routes.php, If it takes wrong path then it redirects to site_url(), where as it should go to page not found? What to do for this?

in routes.php I have wriiten below code.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = 'pagenotfound';
$route['profile/add_to_favorites'] = "profile/add_to_favorites"; 
$route['city/(:any)/welcome/venue_display/(:any)'] = "welcome/venue_display"; 
$route['city'] = "welcome";   `enter code here`
$route['city/(:any)'] = "welcome";
```

Now if I have have opened the link http://mytest.com/city/[any dummy data] , it should redirect to pagenotfound page. But it shoes the data from http://mytest.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it should not.

mytest.com/city/[any dummy data] matches with `$route['city/(:any)']`.